# Access Location on an Android IOT device

Tags: android, iot, android-location, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I have an Android IoT device running Android 5.1.1 on Rockchip RK3288 that as name implies can connect to a WiFi network but doesn't have a GPS or a Cellular module. Whenever I try to access location and find the best location provider it always return me as a 'Passive' provider and hence i have no way of getting my current location.

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
```

I am a bit perplexed that the device has an active network connection but `NETWORK_PROVIDER` isn't available.

Comment: see my answer and let me know your reviews.

Answer (score 1):

> Try Google Geolocation API.

Google Geolocation API use **wifiAccessPoints** and  **cellTowers** too. As you said device don't have GPS and Cellular module you need to use WifiAccessPoints for it.

For WifiAccessPoints you need to pass all your nearest wifi connection data. For E.g In android when click on WIFI it shows list of wifi near to you. So, you need to just pass all that wifi list to WifiAccessPoints so it returns the location of your device.

You can Pass Parameter **"considerIp": "true"** so using your Ip Address it get the current location of your device.

For My Opinion use Get Current location through IP Address which return the Highest Accuracy ratio for current location.This is also said by the Google Maps Geolocation API document.

For more information you can refer [Google Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro) which also provide sample data so that you can check the result from here.

I hope this will give you some hint or get some idea to actually you want to achieve.